# Message database design in a chat app

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm working on a Chat App. You can chat with one person or create(join) a group. I'm considering how the database should be to store all messages.

I come up with two solutions:

Solution 1. Store all messages to one table;

Solution 2. Create a message database for every person or group that user joined.

Solution 1 is easy to achieve, but I don't know if it keep a good performance as the message grows.

The app runs on iOS and I'll use sqlite database. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, having multiple tables with the same structure is one of the signs that your database is not properly [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

If you have separate tables, you cannot easily write queries that must look at multiple persons/groups, such as "With whom did I chat most often recently?"

Your database will grow either way.
You get efficient queries by not having to read all the data, which can be done by writing the queries correctly, and creating appropriate indexes.
See [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html), [The SQLite Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html), and [The Next Generation Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to select latest 10 messages in group "1000" order by `date`, does the query will make database read all the data in the message table? I think your opinion it to use solution1, am I right ?

Comment: That depends on the query and on the database structure.

Comment: Let's say properties of the table are "autoincreasement-id userOrGoupeId groupFlag messageId messageContent date" and the query is `select * message where groupId=1000 order by date DESC limit 10`. Can I make the query more efficient?

Comment: Yes, with an index. But that would be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. Does the article you referenced above talks about index?